# Images can't any longer be found on local server

Tags: visual-studio-code, path, google-chrome-os, localserver

I had a working site with a couple of models, textures and pictures. My Chromebook space was low so I bought a SD-card and copied my localhost folder to that as a backup. Next time i reloaded the server from VS-code with the php-server extenssion i always use. The server responded with a 404 error, I then removed my backupp-folder - thinking maybe that disturbed as a doubble refernce. My server now loads properly but the references to the textures, pictures and modeles no longer work, responding with 404. The referenses between scripts and imports still work, but after the renaming pictures and so forth and restarting
everything, the models, pictures and textures still don't load - it seems permanently cashed some way - Anyone that knows how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

It's solved.The problem was that I once opened the VS-code from the SD card in files - just to try if the card worked for executions. Then I wanted to access the original localhost folder in VS code again. So I opened the localhost folder the same way through files.
My referenses of /localhost/pictures/... then was reffering outside the scope I had accessable in VS code. By removing the folder localhost from the raltive path to /pictures/... the models, textures and pictures could render again.